# Blade linking to a non laravel file in public

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, href, laravel-blade

I have my navigation menu:

```
<li class='{{ ($aktiv == 'rapport') ? 'active' : '' }}'> <a class='rapport' {{HTML::linkRoute('rapport','Rapport')}}</a> </li>
```

How can I link it with href? to the file in this folder, this file is a clean php, non laravel file:

```
'../public/pdf/index.php'
```

Comment: If your view file it's not a .blade.php (you mention clean php) file you won't be able to use blade syntax (E.g. {{}}). You have to use php tags.

Answer (score 3):

i usually use URL, as it already takes the public path as its base.

`{{ URL::to('pdf/index.php') }}`

Comment: note: if used with an absolute url string, the url will be absolute too, not appended to the public path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `public_path()` to point to files in your public folder.

```
<a href="{{ public_path() }}/pdf/index.php">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link to files in the public folder as assets. You can use the `asset()` URL helper for that. E.g. `asset('pdf/index.php')`
It'll create an absolute link that includes your site URL.